# Java - Logging in, I have a few ideas but need to complete them

Tags: java, php, html, authentication

I can make a log in for easily, so that's not the problem. What is my problem is that I don't know how to check if the user's name and password are correct. I had a few ideas so here they are:

1) Saved in game, update every time someone registers -> Not practical

2) A MySQL database with something -> I'm just too stupid for that.

3) A website (php) that asks for ?name= and &password= in the URL, if it exists it echoes true, else false and then when I want to login, I just try to connect to that website (the user won't see that, of course) and see what it returns. I think this is the best idea for me but I don't know how to connect to the website and read what it says.

Just to make it clear, I have a domain and a website.

Comment: "Just to make it clear, I have a domain and a website." Well, you're half way there :). Option 2 is your best bet. Don't do Option 3 for security reasons

Comment: But, but, but I don't know how to use MySQL. :(

Comment: Then learn it. Option 3 will produce security risks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that #1 is really impractical and #3 seems effectively the same as you'd need to store your collection of username / password pairs somewhere. You should really consider #2. At some point we all felt "too stupid" for something new, but check it out, do some tutorials, and I'm sure you'll be well on your way.

An appropriate solution should include password encryption (ideally with a salt). Since you mentioned PHP, check out [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php). Also, take a look at PDO, probably the best (in my opinion) MySQL interface for PHP. Again take a look at the official docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

You seem like you're quite new to this, so some of that may be over your head at first. If so, just Google around with those keywords and you'll be sure to find many great tutorials.

Comment: Can you also tell me if you know, how to connect to website and read what does it echo?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Like, If I want to use the PHP method until I learn MySQL, I know how to make PHP check for password and stuff by reading the URL you are connecting to (?name=  and &pass=), and then if it's correct it echoes "true" or "false". How can I make it with Java so that it goes URL?NAME=NAME&PASS=PASS and then reads if its "true" or "false". Hopefully you understeand what I'm asking for